# Allow to check only one checkbox in test inside while

Tags: jquery, loops, checkbox

I have a while loop where I get data from database:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($skillsResult))
{    

    $id = $row['id'];
    $driver = $row['driver'];
    $subdriver = $row['subdriver'];
    $dep = $row['department'];
    $skill = $row['skills'];
    $vrgood = $row['4'];
    $good = $row['3'];
    $middle = $row['2'];
    $low = $row['1'];
?>

<br/><br/>
<fieldset>
<legend id="q1" class="desc notranslate">
   <?php echo $no++; ?> 
</legend>
<div class="full_qst">
    <div class="drvr"> <?php echo $driver; ?> </div><span class="divider">|</span>
    <div class="sbd_drvr"> <?php echo $subdriver; ?> </div><span class="divider">|</span>
    <div class="qst"> <?php echo $skill; ?> </div>

    <div class="mrk">
        <span>
            <label class="choice" for="q1_a" >
            <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $low ?>"   />
            1</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label class="choice" for="q1_a" >
            <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $middle ?>"    />
            2</label>
        </span>   
        <span>
            <label class="choice" for="q1_a" >
            <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $good ?>"   />
            3</label>
        </span>    
        <span>
            <label class="choice" for="q1_a" >
            <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $vrgood ?>"    />
            4</label>
        </span>
    </div> 
</div>
</fieldset>
<?php
$count++;
}
```

I get around 15 records. What I want is to allow user check checkbox for each line separately and allow them check only on box on same line.
So instead of this:
[image]

I want to get this:[image]

I tried to implement this:

```
$('.mrk input#q').on('change', function() { 
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(':checkbox[name="'  + $(this).prop('name') + '"]').not($(this)).prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

But it deselects previous box on upper line and allow me to choose only one checkbox in whole page. Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine just replace the selector with class `$('input.q')`

But to allow only one checkbox selected per row with same name for all checkboxes will require code like following which will uncheck all the checkbox inside same div and then will check the changed one.

```
$('input.q').on('change', function() { 
    $(this).parents('.full_qst').find(".q[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']").not(this).prop('checked',false); 
});
```

Comment: Works half. it doesn't allow user to check more than one value on the same line however it uncheck value from previous row when i want ot check next one. So it allows me to check only one checkbox

Comment: you need to add the incremented number in checkbox name, once for each row checkboxes name is unique, code will work fine!

Comment: Do you mean I need to do it inside php code? or inside js code? how then I will submit form if names for each row will be different.

Comment: Check updated answer, it will allow you to get the desired behavior with same name!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.siblings()` function for that job and never use same Id on same page for dom element. it only gets your first id and does not see others.

```
$('.mrk input').on('change', function() { 
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked',false);
    }else
      $('.mrk input').prop('checked',false);
});
```

if you do not need to check if this one is checked you can even use

```
$('.mrk input').on('change', function() {
      $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked',false);
});
```

Comment: I still can check few values on same line. But i need to allow user check only one. it means if he already checked 1 and clicks on 2 then 1 is unchecked. I removed id and changed to class also

Comment: ok then the code above should work fine unless you have a different structure on your html. What siblings('input') does is that when you click an input it selects all inputs in parent div. So this should uncheck all of the inputs in div except input you clicked. Other than that did you insert a console log if it is going inside if statement. If you didnt test it and give a feedback please